# Simple way to capture a high quality image with AVCapture

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

All I need to do is capture an image, and all I can find is complicated code on capturing video or multiple frames. I can't use UIImagePickerController because I do not want to see the camera shutter animation and I have a custom overlay, and my app is landscape only. What is the simplest way to manually capture an image from the front or back live camera view in the correct orientation? I don't want to save it to the camera roll, I want to present it in a view controller for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the SquareCam (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple. It contains all what you need for high-quality capture of images. I recently copy-pasted the code from this project myself where I solved the same task as you. It works well :)

Comment: Thanks. Looking into this now. What's with the require/bail stuff in their code? Causing errors for me.

Comment: What sort of errors? If you created new project with ARC support you will need to convert an old code into ARC code also. Apples square cam application written flwithout ARC support :( use an XCode wizard for converting it.

Comment: Btw I just found that there was such question regardin squarecam and ARC support and require/bail :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388853/how-do-you-handle-require-bail-statements-with-arc